# Getting 120V out of a 120V/208V outlet

Tags: wiring

I have a L21-30 receptacle, but I want to power a 120V load that requires a L5-30 receptacle. If I use a L21-30 to L5-30 adapter (PN: [IBX-5158-01](https://www.pduwhips.com/products/2084-l21-30p-to-l5-30r-plug-adapter.aspx)), would I be able to safely power the load? Also, would the load be able to draw 30A through the adapter if needed?

Are there any risks involved in doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The receptacle you've got is for a 3 phase 120/208 WYE service so I doubt it's home inprovement. This adapter takes one of the three 120 legs, the neutral and the ground and sends it to your L5-30 outlet which is 120V 30amp. This will power your load provided that the breaker in th main panel is a 30 amp breaker. The problem with these adapters is that they carry a lot of load and you've got to make sure they are UL listed and not some cheap junk from you know where. If this will be a normal function for use, think about getting the L5-30 outlet hard wired.

Comment: So effectively each 120V leg of L21-30 is rated for 30A?

Comment: In the US at least, there is a breaker on every hot leg and all the same ampacity. So for a straight 120 circuit, a single breaker. For a 120/240 (dryer) or 240 circuit (water heater) a double breaker. For a 3-phase circuit a triple breaker. There **is** an issue at very large sizes - think "entire building" - where the **neutral** may be smaller because the presumption is that the loads are reasonably balanced so that neutral doesn't carry as much as a hot (e.g., if all hots are carrying 30A, neutral carries 0A). However, at the branch circuit level normally neutral is sized (minimum AWG)

Comment: the same as the hots. Ground gets a break because it is expected to carry current only for a very short time during a fault.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this won't work it's just taking one hot from the L21-30 and passing it thru to the L5-30. It says it's rated for 30A / 120V so you should not have any issues

Comment: Does that mean that each leg of L21-30 is rated for 30A?

Comment: Yes, since it's 3-phase they don't carry 30A each at the same time.

Comment: @flamezdude yes, each leg is 30A.  That's why it says -30.  If they meant to say "well 30A worth of 120V but really only 10A on each leg" that would be a -10.